# Get most common colours in an image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Hi I'm using Opencv and I want to find the n most common colors of an image using x sensitivity. How could I do this? Are there any opencv functions to do this?

Cheers!

*Note: this isn't homework, i'm just using opencv for fun!

Comment: no idea what you mean by "x sensitivity", but you could try to cluster the most prominent colors with kmeans()

Comment: Like, say we wanted a shade of gray and another shade of gray to be classified as the same.

Comment: Kinda like with the magic wand in paint!

Comment: Hmm, would it also be possible to show just some sample code or something using kmeans?

Comment: bear with me for not having used it from python so far, maybe the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/clustering.html#cv2.kmeans) help

Comment: Yeah sure, ill have a peak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by "x sensitivity" you mean you want to quantise the image.

You can [cv2.calcHist()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=calchist#calchist) to do that. Without quantisation the histogram will be big (256*256*256).
The link to the documentation has an example how to use calcHist (in C++, not Python but it would be almost the same). Once you have the histogram, just search for the cells with the largest values.

Answer (score 4):

I would transform the images to the HSV color space and then compute a histogram of the H values. Then, take the bins with the largest values.